# Azure App Services, DevOps and Web API deployment

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-devops-rest-api

I am learning Azure. If I developed a Web API project. How exactly is deployed in real-time to Azure App Service? I do saw lot of video where APIs are deployed to Azure App Services. is the way we do in real development? or We use ARM templates? usually,the portal login details are not shared to developer? Once deploy to Azure App Service, How we use Azure DevOps to make CI/CD for the same. Please help/guide with any article/video/tutorial.
or Simply guide how we plan any web app or API from development to Production deployment using Azure App Services and Azure DevOps?
Thanks in Advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

First thing you need to do is maintain GitHub repository.Push all your code inside it !
Now create a web app in Azure under App service !
Once it is deployed you have to deploy the code to it from GitHub.
There are 2 ways to do it from GitHub to maintain CI Cd pipelines.
One way is you use GitHub actions under deployment center to deploy it or other way is create azure DevOps free account and Import GitHub repository there and then push it in Web App.
Both have some end results.
Now about ci cd pipelines anytime you will make changes to code on respective chosen way the code can be seen working in live app.
This all is concept of ci cd pipelines.

Comment: Thanks and appreciate for your answer. if using AzureDevOps ,the Release Pipeline take care of deploying to different environment per the configuration. In Release pipeline we build pipeline to use for auto deployment. If I am current , we can do all this with multiple way.  1. Azure Portal 2. Power Shell commands 3. Azure CLI. am I right?

Comment: Yes, you can do all the deployments through CLI, portal ,PowerShell as well. Point here is that Everytime you have do the manual deployment through these. If this solves your doubt please accept the answer.